# Using IPv6/IPv4 tunneling to send a query to a DNS server - valid or not

Tags: dns, ipv6, rfc, ipv4, tunneling

I was wondering what exactly the standards say about using IPv6/IPv4 tunneling to send a DNS query to a DNS server.  Is this a valid thing to do?  Does anyone know the RFCs (and sections if possible) that talk about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible. Once you have a tunnel, you can do it whatever you want, concerning IPv6.

If you tunnel the trafic f a complete network, other PCs maybe don't even know that they are behind a tunnel.

My PC here, for example, has some IPv4 and some IPv6 entries in the `/etc/resolv.conf`.